# Wordpress captcha in contact form 7?

Tags: wordpress, forms, plugins, captcha, contacts

Hi I'm using contact form 7 with Really Simple CAPTCHA, but it's throwing up the following validation errors.
Is there a way to fix this? Or is there another plugin or can I just enter it into the html?

Thanks for your help

Regards

Judi

```
    #  Line 261, Column 84: document type does not allow element "input" here; missing one of "ins", "del", "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6", "p", "div", "address", "fieldset" start-tag

…llenge_captcha-508" value="20073138" /><img alt="captcha" src="http://www…

✉

The mentioned element is not allowed to appear in the context in which you've placed it; the other mentioned elements are the only ones that are both allowed there and can contain the element mentioned. This might mean that you need a containing element, or possibly that you've forgotten to close a previous element.

One possible cause for this message is that you have attempted to put a block-level element (such as "<p>" or "<table>") inside an inline element (such as "<a>", "<span>", or "<font>").
# Error Line 261, Column 243: document type does not allow element "img" here; missing one of "ins", "del", "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6", "p", "div", "address", "fieldset" start-tag

…/20073138.png" class="wpcf7-captcha-captcha-508" width="72" height="24" /><br/>

✉

The mentioned element is not allowed to appear in the context in which you've placed it; the other mentioned elements are the only ones that are both allowed there and can contain the element mentioned. This might mean that you need a containing element, or possibly that you've forgotten to close a previous element.

One possible cause for this message is that you have attempted to put a block-level element (such as "<p>" or "<table>") inside an inline element (such as "<a>", "<span>", or "<font>").
# Error Line 261, Column 248: document type does not allow element "br" here; missing one of "ins", "del", "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6", "p", "div", "pre", "address", "fieldset" start-tag

…/20073138.png" class="wpcf7-captcha-captcha-508" width="72" height="24" /><br/>

✉

The mentioned element is not allowed to appear in the context in which you've placed it; the other mentioned elements are the only ones that are both allowed there and can contain the element mentioned. This might mean that you need a containing element, or possibly that you've forgotten to close a previous element.

One possible cause for this message is that you have attempted to put a block-level element (such as "<p>" or "<table>") inside an inline element (such as "<a>", "<span>", or "<font>").
# Error Line 262, Column 50: document type does not allow element "span" here; missing one of "ins", "del", "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6", "p", "div", "pre", "address", "fieldset" start-tag

…="wpcf7-form-control-wrap captcha-508"><input type="text" name="captcha-508" v…

✉

The mentioned element is not allowed to appear in the context in which you've placed it; the other mentioned elements are the only ones that are both allowed there and can contain the element mentioned. This might mean that you need a containing element, or possibly that you've forgotten to close a previous element.

One possible cause for this message is that you have attempted to put a block-level element (such as "<p>" or "<table>") inside an inline element (such as "<a>", "<span>", or "<font>").
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin forums say to add this line to wp-config.php to stop `<p>` tags from being inserted, which looks like it will solve some validation problems, according to your error report.

```
define( 'WPCF7_AUTOP', false );
```

But also fix your other errors, as they tend to snowball and cause other validation errors:
[[Invalid]Markup Validation of  artygirl.co.uk  - W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fartygirl.co.uk&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.654). Scroll down in the validation report to see line numbers and source code.